# console.log() with fetched instance halts execution in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I'm using Sequelize in an Express app, and I cannot figure out how to use console.log() in a `async` function. Whenever I want to printout a fetched instance from db, the console log halts the execution.

This is what I've tried (each example in separate tries):

```
updateUser: async (_, { id, ...args }, { User }) => {
  const user = await User.findById(3)
  // will later do some update to user here
  await Promise.resolve(console.log('user: ', user)) // halts the execution
  Promise.resolve(console.log('user: ', user)) // halts the execution
  await console.log('user: ', user) // halts the execution
  console.log('user: ', await user) // halts the execution
  console.log('user: ', user) // halts the execution
  console.log('only a string') // works!
  return user
},
```

I've as well with 0 success tried the following:

```
const user = await User.findById(3).then(user => {
  console.log('user: ', user)
})
```

Comment: What do you mean `console.log()` halts execution?  What exactly happens?  Do you mean your app throws an exception and exits?  What exactly do you mean?  `await` is supposed to pause execution until the promise you are awaiting resolves.  `await` does NOTHING useful when you aren't awaiting a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can only see the first line in the server logs, but then nothing. When removing `console.log` there are a bunch of more operations going on. Here's my first line: Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "firstName", "lastName", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "organizationId" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = '3';

Comment: @jfriend00 Do you mean that I need to remove the async/await to be able to print out a fetched instance or that printing out a fetched instance will never work?

Comment: Since "*`console.log('user: ', user)` halts the execution*" already, this has nothing to do with promises or `await`. Something is wrong with your console or user object.

Comment: @Bergi OK, thank you very much! This cleared up things that I shouldn't blame async/await. I put the model instance in a JSON.stringify() and now it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` stops nothing, `await` does

This will stop execution until `User` has found something :

```
const user = await User.findById(3).then(user => {
  console.log('user: ', user)
})
```

As will this until `aFunction` has a response :

```
const user = await aFunction(anArg).then((do) => something);
```

What you want to do is :

```
var value; // have this somewhere or something similar
aFunction(anArg).then((res) => { value = res; })
```

Or in your case :

```
var savedUser; // have this somewhere or something similar
User.findById(3).then((user) => { savedUser = user; console.log('user: ', user); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `User` object returns a promise, try the following:

```
updateUser: async (_, { id, ...args }, { User }) => {
  const user = await User.findById(3)
  console.log('user: ', user)
  return user
}
```

Comment: I've tried `console.log('user: ', user)` as well, and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

With using the `await` you are actually telling the javascript engine to stop till the promise is resolved.

Update code

```
updateUser: async (_, { id, ...args }, { User }) => {
  const user = await User.findById(3)
  // will later do some update to user here
  Promise.resolve(console.log('user: ', user)) // halts the execution
  console.log('user: ', user) // halts the execution
  console.log('only a string') // works!
  return user
},
```

For more on the async await - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Unfortunately `Promise.resolve(console.log('user: ', user))` doesn't work either..

Comment: I have created an jsfiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/z8wfbrLq/ ) with exactly the same requirement as your and it's working perfectly file. Have a look into it.